# Set Cruise Controls build number to start at a certain value for renamed project?

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

I have a project that uses CruiseControl.NET, and as a versioning scheme we have 3.0.[ccnetbuild].[svnrevision]. CCNetBuild is the internal build number cruise control uses to keep track of how many builds of a project it has done. Now I have had to rename one of the CCNet project (rename in CCNets config file) and the [build] number now starts again from zero. Is there any way I can set it to start at a particular value (the last value I had with the original name) and make it increment from there? It must be stored in some internal CCNet database or something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to edit the `.state` file of the CCNET project. Either you explicitly set its path using the [State Manager Block](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/State+Manager+Blocks) in CCNET configuration or - if omitted - you'll find it in CCNET installation directory.

Comment: +1 This works, note for others that there are 4 references to the build label in the state file. If like me, you just change the first one you see, it won't work...

Comment: This solution is correct, but I had to restart the CC.NET server to get the webdashboard to pick up the changes.

Answer (score 1):

And need to mention that version scheme "3.0.[ccnetbuild].[svnrevision]" is dangerous, because any part of version can't be more than 65535 on Windows OS, so if you expect long life of your project - svnrevision (and maybe even ccnetbuild) can reach this value and at this point will be quite hard to understand what is wrong and why build doesn't work anymore.